# Regex to get MTOM binary PDF content

Tags: php, regex, binary, soap-client, mtom

I am trying to get the MTOM binary content (which is a PDF) using an extended class of SoapClient. 
This is the reference class: https://github.com/debuss/MTOMSoapClient/blob/master/MTOMSoapClient.php

So if you take a look at the class, you can see that I receive a response and then I use regex to get specific parts of it. This is the entire response I get.

**entire response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: ...
Server: .....
Set-Cookie: ....; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ...; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29"; start="<...>"; start-info="text/xml"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

--uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:downloadAttachResponse xmlns:ns2="http://..../"><return><errStr></errStr><result>0</result><contentFile><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:c4d149e6-3f6a-4aa8-bd07-244c92bdc262-2@cxf.apache.org"/></contentFile></return></ns2:downloadAttachResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <c4d149e6-3f6a-4aa8-bd07-244c92bdc262-2@cxf.apache.org>

%PDF-1.4
...

   LOTS OF BINARY CODE HERE FOR THE PDF

--uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29--"
```

**xml response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:downloadAttachResponse xmlns:ns2="http://.../">
         <return>
            <errStr/>
            <result>0</result>
            <contentFile>
               <xop:Include href="cid:c4d149e6-3f6a-4aa8-bd07-244c92bdc262-2@cxf.apache.org" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </contentFile>
         </return>
      </ns2:downloadAttachResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using the code of the class, I get an error on the binary array which is basically empty because the regex doesn't get the pdf content. This is the specific part:

**regex**

```
// Get CID
$cid = null;
preg_match('/cid:([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)@/', $xop_element, $cid);
$cid = $cid[1];

// Get Binary
$binary = null;
preg_match('/Content-ID:[\s\S].+?'.$cid.'[\s\S].+?>([\s\S]*?)--uuid/', $response, $binary);
$binary = trim($binary[1]);   // error here
```

So, how can I get the PDF binary content using regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example data, the Content-ID: part ends with a `>`

```
Content-ID: <c4d149e6-3f6a-4aa8-bd07-244c92bdc262-2@cxf.apache.org>
```

In the pattern that you use, this parts `$cid.'[\s\S].+?>`expects at least a single character `[\s\S]` followed by 1+ times any character non greedy `.+?` which means that there should be at least 2 characters before the `>`

But in the example data, there are no chars between them.

You could update the code to use

```
preg_match('/Content-ID:[\s\S].+?'.$cid.'[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?)--uuid/', $response, $binary);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KrK5f/1)

If the data is always structured like that, you might optimize the pattern a bit:

```
Content-ID:\h+<c4d149e6-3f6a-4aa8-bd07-244c92bdc262-2@cxf.apache.org>\R\s*((?:(?!--uuid).*\R)*)--uuid
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSWDbd/1)

Comment: Thanks! What if I gotta match the content between the two -uuids, considering that that long alphanumeric is every time different and unknown:                                                                
```
--uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29

   LOTS OF BINARY CODE HERE FOR THE PDF

--uuid:0f7fa750-c317-4039-897a-a90685b00d29--"

```

Comment: That depends on the content. You can add the example data to the regex101 link, and at the left top update the regex. Can you share an updated link with an example? https://regex101.com/r/CSWDbd/1

Comment: This photo basically explains: [image](https://pasteboard.co/JahPxJk.jpg). Sorry if I'm not explaining correctly.

Comment: You can make it very specific using a capturing group matching the uuid  and a backreference `\1` to match the same uuid at the end https://regex101.com/r/oao7pq/1 Then the value will be in group 2

Comment: Alright! Thank you soo much! There should be more people like you!